# Cant make Apache/PHP write to directory

Tags: php, apache

On my Centos 8 server the code below writes the string `test string` to the file `/test/test_file.txt` and it works perfectly.

```
shell_exec("sudo echo 'test string' > /test/test_file.txt  2>&1");
```

However, when I try to do that on directories like `/` or `/etc` the file never gets created. So I went to `visudo` and added this:

```
apache ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

But I still cant write to directories like `/` or `/etc`. Is there something I am missing?

I really need to use PHP to create this file. I also tried using `file_put_contents` but it does not work too.

Comment: `So I went to visudo and added this:

apache ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`...you're not a fan of having a secure server then, I take it

Comment: errr.. why on earth you need a public facing interface to write into `/etc`? even worse, giving it a `root` access.

Comment: I know it's not secure, but I am wondering what should I do in order to allow apache user to write to files as if it was root user.

Comment: how about "don't do it"? Why on earth would you need a web application to be able to act as the root user?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why would someone wanna do that But....

To debug this issue.

***Step 1 temporarily disable SELinux*** `sudo setenforce 0`

***Step 2 Check PHP User:*** `<?php echo exec('whoami'); ?>`

***Step 3 Double-check that the sudo privileges*** `<?php echo shell_exec('sudo ls /'); ?>`

Comment: my dear friend `whoami` shows "apache". `sudo ls /` shows all the directories/files correctly. I checked `/etc/selinux/config` and `SELINUX=disabled`. So I am clearly using the `apache` user, I can read but for some reason I cant write.
`

Comment: also, executing directly on the shell `sudo -u apache echo "aa" > /a.txt` works fine. However if I put it inside `shell_exec` it does not work anymore.